# Android: A timer that runs until explicit stop, even if app closed. User starts/stops timer

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager

I want the user to start a timer in the app. It will put out notifications at minute intervals. During this time, user should be able to switch to different activities, leave the app to home screen or go to a different one. Even if app ends, it'd be nice that the timer continues giving notifications until user explicitly stops the timer. Opening app again should allow them to stop it. From what I can tell, sounds like I should go with AlarmManager?  If this thinking is correct, would anyone happen to have a great tutorial that would suit my example well?  Thank you!

EDIT: I didn't have this initially mentioned, but there also needs to be a timer display on the main activity, so some sort of UI interaction is needed. There will be other activities user can go to, but the main activity timer should stay running.

Comment: You can, could also do something like register a receiver for ACTION_TIME_TICK in a foreground service. That would receive the service signal for minute ticks without the need for a manager.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how precisely and how often you shoot your events.
This can be solved by:

1) creating a service, and let it run in the background. Google has nice tutorial here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html .What you are looking for is Service not IntentService. This approach will consume a lot of resources.

2) Using Alarm manager (or if u target Android L you can use the Alarm schedulers)

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

again google has a good tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I had to add a requirement. So far from reading about services, I'm still unsure. Bound services sounded promising, so that I can receive responses back every second to update the mainactivity timer. But if it becomes initially bound to the mainactivity, would the service not be destroyed then?

Comment: You can have a service running in background which does not get destoyed when the activity dies. As u can see here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle when you unbind the service is still running. Also did you think about using CountDownTimer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html